# Can you backup/transfer iOS individual game saves without jalibreaking your device?

Tags: ios

I have both an iPod touch and an iPhone (yes, redundant, I have my reasons), none of them are jailbroken. Some apps I own are installed on both devices, I would like to copy an app's save from one device onto the other. I know that there are apps for jailbroken devices to backup saves but I was wondering if there's a method that doesn't involve jalbreaking (by a third party PC/Mac tool, for example).

(Side note: I know that restoring one device's backup on the other device will transfer all the apps states but that will mean wiping the device completely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a wifi / internet connection, most games should perform syncing with the 'cloud'.

Otherwise, you would need to access where the files are located, usually by some service like: [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) and [PhoneDisk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/).  If you cannot write to where the game files are stored, then **yes, you will need to jailbreak the phone** to gain write privileges.

Comment: "most games should perform syncing with the 'cloud'" I would be very surprised if this is true. Reference?

Comment: Why would you be surprised if this was true?  A bunch of games on ios sync with Gamecenter. The game or application just needs to explicably say that it performs backups to the iCloud (EX Tiny Tower: https://getsatisfaction.com/nimblebit/topics/ios_game_center_backup )

Comment: i would be surprised because making them is my job. A bunch of games is different to most games.

Comment: I ended up using PhoneDisk which is rather handy, I followed this guide http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/22/how-to-transfer-game-saves-between-ios-devices-without-itunes/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have a backup you can use the [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://iphonebackupextractor.com) to retrieve your app data and then import it to your device.