# Can I uninstall and re-install Jetpack Joyride without losing everything?

Tags: ios, jetpack-joyride

So with the latest update, Jetpack Joyride will not get past the loading screen. I am afraid to uninstall and re-install the app because there is the possibility of losing all of my progress and purchases. Does anyone know if I will indeed lose everything or if it will save like some apps do?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I also don't think uninstalling it will help much.  Maybe the game is no longer compatible with your version of iOS?

Comment: I have the latest version. I've also done some research and cannot really find anyone who has had the same problem.

Comment: When you say purchases are you referring to in-game purchases or real money purchases. Typically real money purchases can be restored either within the game or by emailing the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

If you delete it, you will lose all your game data, but things you achieved with Game Centre (eg a new hiscore or an achievement) will be kept on your Game Centre account.

An option will appear when you delete the app to keep the app on Game Centre. Enabling this will keep your achievements and such.

I believe there's no way to keep game data: That will get erased.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your save game is not what causing the crash, you should be able to backup your save to a PC/Mac, delete and reinstall the game, then copy back your backed-up save.

I've done this method with an PC/OSX tool called PhoneDisk, now discontinued and repackged as [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). [This is the guide I've used](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/22/how-to-transfer-game-saves-between-ios-devices-without-itunes/), which I've linked in [an answer to a somewhat similar question of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/57208/4027).

Answer (score -1):

I recently uninstalled an re-installed jetpack. All my in game purchases, S.A.M. rewards and coins where still there. The only thing that happened for me, is I lost all my medals and was back at level one.

P.S. This all happened on an Android device.